# How to override Angular Material styles without using the deprecated ::ng-deep

Tags: css, angular, angular-material

For my project I use `mat-grid` from Angular Material. The text/content of a `mat-grid-tile` is always centered in the middle of the tile. My question is: How can I align the text on the top and/or the right/left?

I didn't find an answer in the docs of Angular Material itself and couldn't find proper help otherwise. The only working solution I found, was based on `::ng-deep`:

```
mat-grid-tile.blue ::ng-deep.mat-figure{    
  background: #2db7f1;    
  color: #FFFFFF;    
  display: flex;    
  justify-content: flex-start; 
}
```

Sadly, the latest version of Angular Material says that `::ng-deep` is deprecated:

[image]

Are there any alternative solutions?

Answer (score 1):

**Ways to avoid ::ng-deep**

I think you bascially have two options if you want to get rid of `::ng-deep`:

- Place your custom css in your global `styles.css`
- Place your custom css in your component.css but set `encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None`

**Please note**: Be aware that for both options your custom css will no longer be scoped, instead it will be applied globally to the entire application.

---

**Reasons why using :host ::ng-deep could be a good idea**

First of all: By adding `:host` in front of "::ng-deep", the styles are applied only to the styles of the elements that are deep in the corresponding component. So thanks to `:host` the styles will not be global.

What's more, `::ng-deep` has no alternative in Angular so far. Even though it is deprecated for two years, there is no clear information when (and if) it will be removed. As a consequence it is still possible to use it. ([Source](https://tomaszs2.medium.com/there-is-no-alternative-to-ng-deep-620496f1c8c9))